getcap/setcap no funciona aunque libcap2-bin esta instalada correctamente
Quiero gestionar mi archivo /usr/bin/dumpcap con getcap, pero al ejecutar
getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap

me dice que
bash~: getcap: command not found

al ejecutar apt install libcap2-bin me dice que ya esta instalada y que esta configurada para configuración manual. Uso linux/debian. Hay otra libreria u otro comando para sustituir a getcap/setcap?
